# How do I make a program listen for keyboard events in the background?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a program that will do multiple keyboard actions when I press my own shortcut (ctrl+q). How do I make my program listen to the binds when the program is in the background?

```
def pasteFun(event):
    messagebox.showinfo("hey")

root.bind("<Control-q>", pasteFun)
```

This works fine when I am in the program, but when I minimize it, ctrl+q does nothing.

```
def test(event):
    messagebox.showinfo("hey","hey")

root.bind_all("<Control-q>",test)
```

I have tried root.bind, frame.bind, and root.bind_all, but my bind does nothing when the program is in the background/minimized.

I need a function to run when I'm outside of the program and hit my binds/shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm making a program that will do multiple keyboard actions when I press my own shortcut (ctrl+q). How do I make my program listen to the binds when the program is in the background?

You can't do that with tkinter. Tkinter will only see events when it has focus. That is a fundamental part of its design.

Comment: How should I go about making it then? Is there a way to make a python script and include some type of GUI?

Answer (score 0):

`pip install pynput`
I think it would be difficult without this type of library.

And we separated the thread so that the keyboard listener does not occupy the main thread.

And create a hotkey by referring to the document at https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
from threading import Thread
from pynput import keyboard

def pasteFun():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("hey")

def hotkey_thread():
    global l
    with keyboard.Listener(
            on_press=for_canonical(hotkey.press),
            on_release=for_canonical(hotkey.release)) as l:
        l.join()

def for_canonical(f):
    return lambda k: f(l.canonical(k))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    hotkey = keyboard.HotKey(keyboard.HotKey.parse('<ctrl>+q'), pasteFun)
    t1 = Thread(target=hotkey_thread)
    t1.start()
    root.mainloop()
```

My code doesn't work completely well, but I hope it gives you some hint.